# Add variable in HtmlXPathSelector select function

Tags: python, scrapy

Instead of "rss", I want to add a global variable to it. So that I don't have to change it again and again.
sel.select('//a[contains(@href, "rss")]/@href').extract() to something like this:
sel.select('//a[contains(@href, url_type)]/@href').extract()

Comment: Can you give more details about what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to read a file which contains a list of domains which I will be crawling one by one. I am looking for links contains certain keywords. Like pdf or rss. I will be reading this keywords from a file. That's why I require a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str.format to insert variable value into xpath expression:

`sel.select('//a[contains(@href, "{0}")]/@href'.format(url_type)).extract()`

Comment: Is it possible to add two statements in select. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. sel.select("//a[contains(@href, "{0}")]/@href | //html/head/link[@type='application/{0}+xml']/@href".format(url_type)).extract()

Comment: Yes, it's possible, just don't confuse quotes:  
'//a[contains(@href, "{0}")]/@href | //html/head/link[@type="application/{0}+xml"]/@href'.format(url_type)